# react-redux v6 a v3.*.* version of react-redux-firebase is required

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, version, react-redux-firebase

I've been working on a project using react-redux-firebase, which has worked for me before. today I got the following error:

[image: chrome error message]

I'm not sure if the error is somewhere else in my code or if I have to update react-redux-firebase to version 3.*.*, which doesn't seem to exist as of now. Has anyone else had this issue? I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

Here are the dependencies in my package.json:

`"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^5.7.0",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-redux-firebase": "^2.2.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-firestore": "^0.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },`

This is what my index.js file looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { 
  createStore, 
  applyMiddleware, 
  compose 
} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './store/reducers/index';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { reduxFirestore, getFirestore } from 'redux-firestore';
import { reactReduxFirebase, getFirebase } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import fbConfig from './firebase/fbConfig';

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(
      thunk.withExtraArgument({
        getFirebase,
        getFirestore
      })),
      reduxFirestore(fbConfig),
      reactReduxFirebase(fbConfig)
  )
);

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));


serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Answer (score 18):

1- Download v3 as following:

```
npm i --save react-redux-firebase@latest
```

Then you can refactor your code to work with v3 as written here in the docs:
https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/tree/next

2- Or just use react-redux v5.1.1

```
npm i --save react-redux@^5.0.0
```

Comment: The second option worked for me but I had to restart my application (i.e. ctrl-C and then `npm start` again).

Comment: I had to use `npm i --save react-redux-firebase@next` to get v3

Answer (score 8):

Just downgrade to react-redux@5.1.1 and react-redux-firebase@2.2.4 to fix this error. Using framework and boilerplate code in your app is a blessing and a curse at the same time.

Run these commands ....

```
npm -i react-redux@5.1.1
npm -i react-redux-firebase@2.2.4
```

Or these

```
npm i --save react-redux@5.1.1
npm i --save react-redux-firebase@2.2.4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can install v3 with `npm i --save react-redux-firebase@next` for now.

from http://docs.react-redux-firebase.com/history/v3.0.0/

> Interested in support for react-redux@^6 or the new react context API? Checkout the next branch which contains the next upcoming major version (installed through `npm i --save react-redux-firebase@next`).

Answer (score 1):

Use this :
npm install react-redux@5.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Running `yarn add react-redux-firebase@next`, and going through the documentation of firebase version3 helped me fix the issue. Here is the [documentation](http://docs.react-redux-firebase.com/history/v3.0.0/docs/firestore.html)

Answer (score 1):

After struggling quite a bit with learning this (in part due to an outdated course on Udemy) I found that `npm i --s react-redux-firebase@latest` was downloading 2.4.0.

```
npm i --s react-redux-firebase@next
```

The above did the trick and returned `react-redux-firebase@3.0.0-alpha.16`